# Is it possible to make this more efficient?

Tags: javascript, performance, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I've written a Google Sheets script to calculate the number of bottles that will be required given x amount of customers and y amount of shots per bottle.

i.e.
`=BOTTLES_REQUIRED(1,22)` #=> 1
`=BOTTLES_REQURIED(22,22)` #=> 1
`=BOTTLES_REQUIRED(23,22)` #=> 2

```
function BOTTLES_REQUIRED(customers, shots_per_bottle) {

  var bottles_required = 1;
  var shots = 0;

  for(var i = 0; i < customers; i++) {
    shots++;

    if( shots > shots_per_bottle ) {
       bottles_required++;
       shots = 0;
    }
  }

   return bottles_required;
}
```

It takes a while to run though at times, is there a more efficient way of writing this?

Comment: ?? Isn't this simply `bottles_required = Math.ceil (customers / shots_per_bottle)`?

Comment: Yes, but then you don't get the remaining shots that are left in the bottle, but we can sneak that behind the bar right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not using math for this?

```
function BOTTLES_REQUIRED(customers, shots_per_bottle) {
    return Math.ceil(customers / shots_per_bottle);
}
```

look at this [jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/n567sg3u/).